# Magento 2 in custom grid click action result redirect given object object

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, order-grid, renderer

I have created my custom grid increment id is click to result in redirect sales order view page. But given the action return object object.[image]

file-path

vender/module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/assignorder_changeemail_listing.xml

```
<column name="order_id" class="vender\module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\ViewAction">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <!-- <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order_Id</item>-->
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">order_id</item>
                    <item name="viewUrlPath" xsi:type="string">sales/order/view</item>
                    <item name="urlEntityParamName" xsi:type="string">order_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
```

path of ViewAction.php: vender\module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

```
<?php
namespace vender\module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;

class ViewAction extends Column
{
    protected $urlBuilder;

    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                if (isset($item['order_id'])) {
                    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                    $incrId = $item['order_id'];
                    $collection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order');
                    $orderInfo = $collection->loadByIncrementId($incrId);
                    $orderId = $orderInfo ->getId();
                    $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
                    $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
                    $logger->addWriter($writer);
                    $logger->info($item['order_id']);
                    $viewUrlPath = $this->getData('config/viewUrlPath') ?: '#';
                    $urlEntityParamName = $this->getData('config/urlEntityParamName') ?: $orderId;
                    $item[$this->getData('name')] = [
                        'view' => [
                            'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                                $viewUrlPath,
                                [
                                    $urlEntityParamName => $orderId
                                ]
                            ),
                            'label' => __('view')
                        ]
                    ];
                }
            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not getting Order Id in your file?

Comment: yes, Order id get here.But return object object.